# SDL2 get keymapped / "cooked" code for a keypress event?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to "cook" a modifier + keycode as received from SDL_KEYDOWN events, into what the combination represents in the current OS keymap.

In SDL1, this was available in the keysym.unicode field, but this is gone in SDL2.

Instead, you're supposed to listen to SDL_TEXTINPUT events for this, which does work, but the problem is they come *after* the corresponding SDL_KEYDOWN events, so if you have for example a hotkey that you use and want to react to, which could need to be a part of a composite key, you get into trouble.

More specifically, I'm trying to react to the '/' press, in the current keymap, to open an admin command box in a game. But on my keymap, / is reached with Shift+7, and I'm already using 7 as a hotkey for other stuff and don't want to trig that other stuff in the Shift+7 case (but I can't know from the game that it's the particular Shift+7 which represents '/'!)

In SDL2, I get these events in this order:

- SDL_KEYDOWN for L_SHIFT
- SDL_KEYDOWN for 7
- SDL_TEXTINPUT for '/'

One workaround I was going to ask about is if there was a way to "cook" the "L_SHIFT + '7'" combination into '/' myself, this way I could check this immediately on the SDL_KEYDOWN for 7, before waiting for an SDL_TEXTINPUT event.

In SDL1 on the other hand, I would get:

- SDL_KEYDOWN for L_SHIFT
- SDL_KEYDOWN for '7' with keysym.unicode field set to '/'

which worked fine (and also worked then for keymaps that had '/' on a dedicated key).